# Ionic deployment to device not working with latest update

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have recently updated my ionic cli to the latest version. Now I am unable to deploy my app onto the device. Please see the output of my `ionic info` command

```
cli packages: 

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Node : v6.10.0
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 7
```

and whenever I run `ionic cordova run android` command it simply shows the following output and doesn't deploy app onto the device. I tried running new command as mentioned in the docs `ionic cordova run android --device` no change same output. How can i resolve this issue?

```
    cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> cordova platform save
√ Running command - done!
[INFO] Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova

[06:44:35]  build dev started ...
[06:44:35]  clean started ...
[06:44:35]  clean finished in 7 ms
[06:44:35]  copy started ...
[06:44:35]  transpile started ...
[06:44:39]  transpile finished in 4.53 s
[06:44:39]  preprocess started ...
[06:44:39]  deeplinks started ...
[06:44:39]  deeplinks finished in 63 ms
[06:44:39]  preprocess finished in 63 ms
[06:44:39]  webpack started ...
[06:44:40]  copy finished in 5.48 s
[06:44:51]  webpack finished in 11.90 s
[06:44:51]  sass started ...
[06:44:53]  sass finished in 1.46 s
[06:44:53]  postprocess started ...
[06:44:53]  removed unused font files
[06:44:53]  postprocess finished in 30 ms
[06:44:53]  lint started ...
[06:44:53]  build dev finished in 18.38 s
> ionic cordova prepare
[WARN] No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare.

       You can save your installed platforms to config.xml with the ionic cordova platform save command.
[06:44:57]  lint finished in 4.42 s
```

Comment: Could you please check that if you add/remove the platform using the `--save` flag, the `config.xml` file is being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to add the platform with cordova CLI

```
cordova add platform [PLATFORM_TAG]
```

PLATFORM_TAG (Android or ios)

Comment: Above command not working i tried  with 'ionic cordova platform add android' and ran 'ionic cordova run android --device' same output nochange

Comment: I have removed and added platform its working as expected . Thank you :)